# Magento - Canonical URL for catagory page is not taking

Tags: magento-1.9, category, xml

I am trying to add a canonical URL in category page custom design. But it is not taking.

Here is my code,

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>technopro/vendors/js/moment.min.js</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>technopro/vendors/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>slider/slick.css</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>slider/slick-theme.css</name></action>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>slider/slick.js</name></action>
    <action method=”removeItem”>
        <type>link_rel</type>
        <name>https://www.examplesite.com/cochin/mri-scan-cost</name>
    </action>
    <action method=”addLinkRel”>
        <rel>canonical</rel>
        <href>https://www.examplesite.com/cochin/mri-scan-cost/</href>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="forms/forms" template="healthcheckupforms/mriscan.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Canonical URL is not taking it is showing in source code as,

`a href="https://www.examplesite.com/cochin/mri-scan-cost"`

But it should be shown as,

`link rel="canonical" href="https://www.examplesite.com/cochin/mri-scan-cost"`

Answer (score 1):

Change below code it seems double quote is not proper

```
”removeItem”
```

to

```
"removeItem"
```

And below one as well:

```
”addLinkRel”
```

to

```
"addLinkRel"
```

Comment: Thnkyou prashant :)

Comment: If it is solution you can accept it so it will help others